# /couchbase_ext.so: undefined symbol: lcb_create_io_ops

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I am trying to us couchbase ruby, but when I attempt connect I receive this error:

```
/couchbase_ext.so: undefined symbol: lcb_create_io_ops
```

I am using this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'couchbase'


client = Couchbase.connect(:bucket => "domain",
                           :hostname => "localhost" )
client.get("dominio.test")

client.disconnect
```

I am using

- amazon ec2 instance
- ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
- libcouchbase-devel-2.2.0-1.x86_64

and response for ldd $(gem which couchbase_ext.so) is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff541ff000)
    libruby.so.2.0 => /home/yvillar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/libruby.so.2.0 (0x00007fedd2afd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fedd28d7000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fedd26cf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fedd24cb000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fedd2293000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fedd2010000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fedd1c84000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fedd319d000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fedd1a21000)
```

Comment: What is the output of this command?
    ruby -rcouchbase -e 'puts Couchbase::VERSION'

My C libcouchbase libraries are on version 2.2.0-2453, perhaps try upgrading those. My ruby client gem is version 1.3.3

Comment: Could you include output of this command? `ldd $(gem which couchbase_ext.so)`

Comment: response for ruby -rcouchbase -e 'puts Couchbase::VERSION' is 1.3.3